# ¿Cómo hacer que la reproducción de audio con TextToSpeech se detenga al cerrar la aplicación en Android?

Tags: android, audio

Tengo una aplicación en [android](/questions/tagged/android)  en la cual doy la posibilidad de leer grandes cantidades de texto.

La tecnología `TextToSpeech` a través de la cual Android permite hacer esto tiene varias limitaciones, entre ellas, el no permitir leer de un golpe más de 4,000 caracteres.

El hecho es que logré crear una clase que me permite dividir adecuadamente textos de mucha longitud y leerlo.

La clase es esta:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;


public class TTS {
    private static final String TAG = "TTSClass";
    private static TextToSpeech tts;
    private String strActual = "0";
    private String strPrevia = "0";
    private int i = 0;
    private int x = 0;
    private int MAXIMO = 0;
    private String[] strContenido;

    public TTS(final Context context, String[] contenido) {

        this.strContenido = contenido;
        tts = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                MAXIMO = TextToSpeech.getMaxSpeechInputLength();
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    final Locale locSpanish = new Locale("spa", "ESP");
                    int result = tts.setLanguage(locSpanish);
                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Lenguaje no soportado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(
                                new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onStart(String s) {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onDone(String s) {
                                        for (String textos : strContenido) {
                                            i = 1;
                                            x = i - 1;
                                            String sb = "" +
                                                    i;
                                            strActual = sb;

                                            String sbX = "" +
                                                    x;
                                            strPrevia = sbX;

                                            if (s.equals(strPrevia) && (strActual.length() < MAXIMO)) {
                                                leerTexto(textos, strActual);
                                                i++;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        leerTexto("Fin de la lectura", "fin");
                                        if (s.equals("fin")) {
                                            cerrar();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(String s) {
                                        //Log.i(TAG, "Error: " + s + "error:" + TextToSpeech.ERROR);
                                    }
                                });

                        leerTexto("Iniciando lectura", "0");
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Falló la inicialización", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }


    private void leerTexto(String strTexto, String strId) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            //API 21+
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            tts.speak(strTexto, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, bundle, strId);

        } else {
            //API 15-
            HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            tts.speak(strTexto, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, param);
        }
    }

    private void cerrar() {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
}
```

No se fijen demasiado en el método `onDone`, el cual puede parecer algo *rocambolesco* :) Es la mejor solución que he encontrado (por ahora) para ir pasando al lector cada paquete de lectura previamente dividido en un array. Ese no es el problema, la clase funciona.

Mi problema es el siguiente: **si lanzo una lectura de texto y cierro la aplicación, la lectura continúa.** Para detenerla, tengo que cerrar todas las aplicaciones que están abiertas en el background.

Recuerdo que en algunas pruebas, el audio se detenía cuando cerraba la aplicación y realmente no sé si hice algún cambio que permite que el audio siga corriendo aún con la app cerrada. Lo que parece ocurrir es que el código transfiere el audio al reproductor nativo del dispositivo para que lo lea de forma independiente a la app (entiendo yo que por eso continúa cuando la app se cierra y sólo se detiene cuando se cierran todas las apps abiertas en el background).

**¿Conocen alguna manera de ligar la reproducción de audio a la app, de forma que al cerrar la app, se cierre también la reproducción de audio?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me respondo a mí mismo:

En la `Activity` que lanza la lectura por voz tengo esto:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.item_voz) {
        String[] strTexto = strContenido.toString().split(SEPARADOR);
        tts=new TTS(getApplicationContext(), strTexto);
    }
```

He logrado detener la reproducción de voz invocando al método `cerrar` de mi clase `TTS` desde el método `onStop` de la `Activity` que lanza la lectura:

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    if(tts != null) {
        tts.cerrar();
    }

}
```

De este modo, cuando cierro la `Activity`, la reproducción se detiene.