# ¿Cómo se controla la vuelta atrás desde la barra de tareas en Android?

Tags: android

En mi aplicación yo lanzo una lectura de texto por voz, la cual quiero que se detenga cuando el usuario vuelve hacia atrás, sea pulsando el botón del dispositivo, sea pulsando el botón volver atrás que aparece en la barra de tareas.

Puse este código:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.cerrar();
    }
}
```

Y cuando presiono el botón del dispositivo, la lectura se detiene.

Leí que para controlar el botón de la barra de tareas había que hacer esto en el método `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
    if (id == R.id.home) {
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.cerrar();
        }
```

Pero resulta que no funciona. ¿Alguien sabe cómo controlar la pulsación de ese botón, para poder desde ella detener el audio?

> Pregunta relacionada: [¿Cómo hacer que la reproducción de audio con TextToSpeech se detenga al cerrar la aplicación en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/176978/29967) Esta
>   pregunta no resolvió mi problema, porque la lectura se detenía cuando
>   la pantalla del dispositivo entraba en reposo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me respondo a mí mismo, por si puede servir a otros en el futuro.

Mi error era que yo estaba poniendo el id del botón así:

<s>`if (id == R.id.home) {`</s>

Y debo ponerlo así:

`if (id == android.R.id.home) {`

Viene explicado en el apartado [***Providing Up navigation***](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral) de Android.

El código completo sería así mas o menos:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        //Aquí se puede cerrar la reproducción
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Además ellos recomiendan usar las APIs `NavUtils` si la actividad actual tiene una actividad padre:

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
        ...
    </activity>
    <!-- A child of the main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```